# Image background to a div and another image in top using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to HTML and Bootstrap and I am trying to learn it. I have came to a situation, where the images don't display at all.

First image should be full background for the first div and second image, smaller, should be in the top right, using bootstrap.

If someone has any idea please give a hand.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        .top {
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            min-height: 100%;
            min-width: 1024px;
            background: url('images/img1.jpg') no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;

        }
        .top .text {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            top: 132px;
            right: 351px;
            background-image: url('images/img2.jpg') no-repeat;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class=" top container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="text col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-5">
            <p>Hello</p>
        </div>
    </div>      
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! It would be really helpful if you could paste the above into a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com) or something and link to it here. Then we can see what's happening for ourselves. In addition, IMHO it works better if I learn a language without adding a library first.

Comment: There is a mistake , you have not linked your bootstrap css and js fille in your head tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to put your `min-height` in `.top` according to your mobile device or your smallest device not 100%. and `.next` the `height:auto;`. also your min-width is too much large value, so please decrease it as your device width.

Comment: Thank you, works now. I learned something new today from you Ankin and from the other 2 guys.

Comment: Its our duty John :) .

Answer (score 0):

In the second class you are using a `background-image` simply say `background` as in the first one.

```
.top .text {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        top: 132px;
        right: 351px;
        background: url('images/img2.jpg') no-repeat;
        border: 1px solid;
    }
```

And you are using "position: absolute" for the second div so the first one have no content and therefore `height: 100%` will not do anything either put `height` in pixels or put some content inside the `div` to make it scale in height.